# How to mark checked all checkboxes from jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I want to check and uncheck a list of check boxes with single click using JavaScript:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="All" value="All" checked="checked" id="SelectAll1" class="MemberSelectcheckBox1" /></td>
    <td width="90%"><strong>Field Name</strong>:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="FirstName" value="1" id="FirstName" class="MemberSelectcheckBox1" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>First Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Surname" value="1" id="Surname" class="MemberSelectcheckBox1" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>Surname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Email" value="1" id="Email" class="MemberSelectcheckBox1" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Phone" value="1" id="Phone" class="MemberSelectcheckBox1" checked="checked"></td>
    <td>Phone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

and JavaScript as mentioned below it only works for unchecked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#SelectAll1").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        //$(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").attr('checked','checked');
    }else{
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: use `.change()` instead of `.click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution; use `.prop()` instead of `attr()` and `removeAttr()`, and it's better to use `on()` instead of `click()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.#SelectAll1', function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop("checked",false); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$("#SelectAll1").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Check the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ME7nV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `.attr()` to alter the state of a property, use `.prop()` instead.

See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

As pointed out in the comments, use the `.change()` handler instead of the `.click()` handler, or toggling via keyboard will not be picked up.

You can also simplify the code then to:

```
$("#SelectAll1").change(function() {
    $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#SelectAll1").click(function() {
    $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //$(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it will help:

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})       

<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> <b>Check All</b>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Box1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Box2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Box3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#SelectAll1").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
        });
    }else{
        $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr('checked', true)` will not work in `jquery > 1.9`. Hence use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Try this:

```
$("#SelectAll1").change(function() {
    $.each($('[class=MemberSelectcheckBox1]'), function (i, item) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").prop('checked', true);

        } else {
            $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55FaS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#SelectAll1").click(function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(isChecked) {
           $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").attr({checked:true});
        } else {
            $(".MemberSelectcheckBox1").attr({checked:false});

        }
    });
```

Comment: there is no need for an each() loop for class selector as in few answers